# Where did my rsync'd file go?

Tags: file-transfer, rsync

I just copied a very large file (> 10 gb) from one EC2 server to another using rsync:

```
rsync -asv -P xtrabackup_2012_07_08_21h20m.tar.gz staging:/mnt/backups
```

This took a couple of hours. Then, *after* reaching 100% on the transfer, I saw this error:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/.backups.rqGSSe" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

Now, I get that this was probably my fault. I didn't even create the "backups" directory on the target machine (totally just forgot); and anyway, I might not have set up the folder permissions properly either. **But**: where did the file go?

If possible I'd like to fix whatever issues caused the "Permission denied" error and then just copy the data from rsync to the /mnt/backups directory. But I can't find it anywhere. It took all that time to transfer; surely it's sitting on the hard disk somewhere, right?